# Empty Query getting attached to main URL .htaccess issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess to clean up my URL. It works fine generally when clicking on different links like www.example.com/el-nino-effect. However when I go to www.example.com explicitly, it takes me to www.example.com/index?iden= rather than just www.example.com. Though they are the same page, this primary URL somehow screws up. Can you help?

The 4th para is where the cleaner URL code is present in the .htaccess, but I'm posting the whole file nonetheless. Also funnily, this problem is not happening in Chrome Browser on Ubuntu, but is happening on the Chrome browser on a chromebook.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# For cleaner URLs making ?q=el-nino to /el-nino
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?iden=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?iden=$1 [L]
# RewriteRule ^downloads/([^/\.]+)/?$ downloads.php?id=$1 [L]

# For rewriting to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your rules look fine but they are not in right order. In general keep redirect rules before internal rewrites like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For rewriting to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## hide .php extension snippet
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# For cleaner URLs making ?q=el-nino to /el-nino
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?iden=$1 [L,QSA]
# RewriteRule ^downloads/([^/\.]+)/?$ downloads.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test this after clearing your browser cache.